# In a spinless system with time reversal symmetry, is $E_n(k)=E_n(-k)$ always true?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am studying TR-symmetry from: [*"Group Theory"*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-540-32899-5_16.pdf) by Dresselhaus, Dresselhaus and Jorio and there's a point that I cannot quite understand. The point is under eq. (16.17).

In general, we know that the time reversal operator $\Theta$ acts on a Bloch state with band index $n$ (which is omitted in the above reference) and wave-vector $k$ (although here I am only treating the 1D case), $\psi_{nk}$, as follows $$\Theta\psi_{nk}=\psi^*_{nk}$$
Now, the translation operator $\hat{T}_R$ acts as follows
$$\hat{T}_R\psi_{nk}=e^{ikR}\psi_{nk}$$
$$\hat{T}_R\psi^*_{nk}=e^{i(-k)R}\psi^*_{nk}$$
Therefore, $\psi_{nk}^*$ corresponds to $-k$.

Now, the author says that, for nondegerate levels, we should identify $\psi_{nk}^*=\psi_{n-k}$. As I understand this, this is because we already know that for the $n$-th band and at $-k$ in the first Brillouin zone there is already the state $\psi_{n-k}$, so in order to not have more than one state there, we have to make the above identification.

The author then proceeds on by saying that for an (at least) doubly degenerate level, we cannot make the above identification and we have at least two states at $(n,-k)$, namely $\psi_{n-k}$ and $\psi^*_{nk}$ (again, correct me if I am not getting something right here).

*Then* the author says that if the system has time reversal symmetry,  by $[\hat{H},\hat{\Theta}]=0$, we have that $$\hat{H}\psi^*_{nk}=E_n(k)\psi^*_{nk}.$$ 
So, in the nondegenerate case, this translates as $$\hat{H}\psi_{n-k}=E_n(k)\psi_{n-k}$$ so that $$E_n(k)=E_n(-k).$$ 
While, for the doubly degenerate case we have that $$\psi^*_{nk}\neq\psi_{n-k}$$ and they are distinct states. So, we just have $\hat{H}\psi^*_{nk}=E_n(k)\psi^*_{nk}$ which implies that for each $(n,k)$ we have (at least) two states, namely we have $\psi_{nk}$ and $\psi^*_{nk}$ for each $E_n(k)$.

I have three questions about this:

1. Is my above understanding correct? If so, then what restrictions does time reversal symmetry impose on the states? Because as I understand it, it only imposes restrictions on the band structure.
2. For the doubly degenerate case, even if $\psi^*_{nk}\neq\psi_{n-k}$, the state $\psi^*_{nk}$ still corresponds to $-k$ and energy $E_n(k)$, so could we again conclude that $E_n(k)=E_n(-k)$?
3. For the nondegenerate case, we can conclude that the Berry curvature is equal to zero. But what can we conclude about the Berry curvature in the non-degenerate case?

Comment: Could you explain a little more clearly in the beginning of your question what exactly $\psi$, $n$, and $k$ represent here, especially as it pertains to what's in that paper?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan I hope my new edit helps.